# Simulating an independent samples t-test with integer scores

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, t-test, binomial-distribution, simulation

In many research studies, researchers use measurement tools which produce ***scores that are all in integers***. When such tools are applied to 2 groups of subjects, researchers use *independent-samples t-test* as a formal statistical test between the two groups.

(**Note:** these integer scores are not Likert scale data, RATHER these integers usually result from a test with $n$ items each dichotomously scored (i.e., ${0, 1}$), each subject's score is SUM of these $n$ items, which is necessarily an integer).

## Question

Given the equality of population variances assumption for the t-test, how can I simulate the above t-test scenario while data are in the integer form?

## What I have tried

I could think of this scenario as drawing from ***2 binomial distributions*** with one binomial for ***"group 1"*** set to have a tiny bit higher mean compared to ***"group 2"***. But the problem with this set-up is that, the equality of population variances is violated. That is, increasing ***"group 1's"*** mean by just a bit increasing its `probability of success` will necessarily decrease ***"group 1's"*** variance compared to the variance of ***"group 2"*** and this violates the equality of variances assumption.

**Here is my R code:**

```
n1 = 30; n2 = 30 ; p1 = .52 ; p2 = .5 ; max.score = 15

y = as.vector(unlist(mapply(FUN = rbinom, n = c(n1, n2), size = c(max.score, max.score), prob = c(p1, p2))))

  groups = factor( rep(1:2, times = c(n1, n2)) )

cbind(m1 = mean(y[groups == 1]), m2 = mean(y[groups == 2]), sd1 = sd(y[groups == 1]), sd2 = sd(y[groups == 2]) )

(t.value = unname(t.test(y ~ groups, var.equal = TRUE)[[1]]) )
```

Comment: 1. "*researchers use independent-samples t-test*" ... well *some* researchers, sure, but many don't.  2. I don't think a binomial is a suitable model for the kinds of data you're talking about (presumably Likert scales ... sums of individual Likert items). Binomial will tend to have too little variation (and not enough flexibility of shape) compared to real data

Comment: @Glen_b, could you please let me know what would be suitable distribution  in your view? So, this is not Likert scales data, these are **SUM** of ${0, 1}$ (i.e., dichotomousely scored) items from a test with $n$ items, so **each subject's score** is SUM of these ${0, 1}$ items which forms necessarily an integer. That's why I thought of a binomial distribution?

Comment: Oh, okay. My apologies; yes, a binomial may be a reasonable first approximation if there's not a lot of variation in the probability of a 1 across items within a single total. The general case is [*Poisson-binomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), which in different situations *may* have one of several reasonable approximations. Another possible approach for modeling it is via is a quasi-binomial (though this is only suitable for *fitting* a model, not simulating one)

Comment: @Glen_b, I'm applied researcher, but obviously very interested in learning. Would you mind showing one of the approaches you're suggesting as a response? I deeply appreciate it.

Comment: A simulation of a Poisson binomial is just like simulating a binomial but you let the p vary across trials (components); I can't really tell you what sets of $p$'s you should use. So for example for one observation you might have `p=rep(c(.20,.24,.36,.55,.78),3);sum(rbinom(15,1,p))`. The effort comes into figuring out how a whole vector of $p$'s will vary in your simulation. You might of course consider some continuous mixture distribution, such as a [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution)

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you. I guess we might have a good R package to generate beta-binomial random variables? But let me ask a more fundamental question. ***Which of the following is a more reasonable approach:***  **(1)** We say that binomial distribution really is the appropriate underlying distribution for the sum of $({0, 1})$ item scores BUT **t-test** is inappropriate to compare such item scores from 2 groups? OR **(2)** We say that t-test is appropriate BUT **binomial distribution** is inappropriate to be the generator of the above item scores?

Comment: 1. I don't claim the t-test is appropriate or not -- it depends! I could suggest some values of $p$ for which it would not and others where it would be fine. Wasn't figuring out if the t-test would work okay for whatever circumstances you had in mind the point of the simulation in the first place? 2. I can't tell you whether the binomial suits your circumstances or not *because I don't know how much your $p$'s should vary!*. You're asking me to tell you what you should be telling us. ... it may well be that the binomal is fine and the t-test is fine or it may be that neither is okay.

Comment: 3. there may well be a package for the beta binomial but you don't need it; it's trivial to simulate from. Once you choose your beta parameters ($a$ and $b$ say) and the number of components, you can just do `p=rbeta(n,a,b);sum(rbinom(n,1,p))`. I should probably offer an answer but it's hard to see how to pull an answer out of all that. (Oh, if you want your individual p's to be similar across individuals or across the groups you'll need some way to do that.)

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you so much, given a t-test in mind, the idea of the simulation is to ***"mimic"*** actual studies in my field (all of which do t-test). Specially, if think *p's* could vary a whole lot (e.g., $Beta(2, 2)$), then could we maintain the assumption of equality of variance across the groups IF we want to give one of the groups (here *group 1*) a bit **higher mean** compared to the other group?  IF NO, then what other test can help us compare the performances between 2 such groups of integer scores?

Comment: When you transform a discrete variable you'll always get a discrete variable back out, and it can't even gain any additional distinct values over the number it started with. Indeed, if the transformation is strictly monotonic (generally what you'd restrict yourself to) it can't lose any either -- you always have a sample which is just as discrete as when you began, the only thing that changes is the gaps between those distinct values. However, to satisfy the assumptions *exactly* would require you sample from normal distributions, which are continuous. This is therefore impossible.

Comment: @Glen_b, sure, I appreciate it. So, I want to better understand your ***beta-binomial approach***. How this approach can help us if I tell you, the $p$ vector will be distributed as a $Beta(2,2)$? Using the approach, Are we going to do a t-test between the groups then?

Comment: Weird, your comment of (currently) 14 hours ago looked completely different on my screen when I answered it before. When you say "the p-vector" there's not just one p-vector; you can say one of the groups has a $p\sim B(2,2)$ but to make the other have a different mean you'd have to change the parameters. You can make the mean larger or smaller by varying the ratio of a to b. You usually can't hold the variance constant, since the variance of a binomial depends on its parameters (variance for small p's or p's near 1 is naturally smaller than if p is in the middle or varying up and down a lot)

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you so much. Would that be possible that tomorrow (if you get a chance) you kindly write an answer just based on this approach?